# Understanding my Gson Parser code in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a code and I want to understand what that code exactly does line by line as I am new to Java and want to get an understanding of that program.

The code I have is the following:

```
public class json {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("file"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonElement.class);

            //JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);

            JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonObject().get("rows").getAsJsonArray();
            int length = array.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                System.out.println(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("automatic").getAsJsonObject().get("kernel").getAsJsonObject().get("release").getAsString());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

When I run it I get:

```
3.16.0-5-amd64
3.16.0-5-amd64
3.16.0-5-amd64
```

The program does what I needed, but there are 1 or 2 lines which don't understand 100%.

So `JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("file"));` Reads the json file

This creates a Gson object `Gson gson = new Gson();`

Here I create an Element "json" where I save all the content from the json file inside right? `JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonElement.class);`

This line creates an Array were I search "rows" inside the content of "json" right? `JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonObject().get("rows").getAsJsonArray();`

So `int length = array.size();` creates and integer called "lenght".. but what does `array.size();` exactly do?

The loop I understand I guess.. It just goes through the object and searches for the content of the keywords I need and prints them out..

Comment: The method size refers to the JsonArray object and returns the number of elements in your JsonArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the comments in the following code:

```java
public class json {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        // This creates a JsonReader object which allows for reading in JSON from a stream
        // You are creating this object with the input of a FileReader, establishing the input stream as that of the file "file"
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("file"));

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // This object stores the JSON result of reading in the input from the file "file" by using the jsonReader object to do so
        // Remember that the jsonReader uses a FileReader under the hood, because that is how you defined it
        JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonElement.class);

        JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonObject().get("rows").getAsJsonArray();
        int length = array.size(); // This returns the number of elements in your JsonArray array and stores it in the length variable
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("automatic").getAsJsonObject().get("kernel").getAsJsonObject().get("release").getAsString());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```